# Operação em PHP. Multiplicação usando porcentagem

Tags: php

```
<?php echo $i['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice'][0]['__value__']; ?>
```

Como posso multifiplcar `'__value__'` por 2 e depois somar 60% ao valor total?

Exemplo:

```
Valor = 10
Multiplica por 2 = 20
Acrescenta 60% = 20 * 60% = 12
Total = 20 + 12 = 32.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Versão "curta":

```
<?php echo $i['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice'][0]['__value__'] * 3.2 ;>
```

### Explicação:

Calcular acréscimo de 60% é a mesma coisa que multiplicar por 1.6.
Afinal 100% = 1, portanto 60% = 0.6.
Como queremos acréscimo, queremos 100% + 60%, ou seja multiplicando por (1 + 0.6) => (1.6)

Se você quer multiplicar por 2 e depois acrescentar os 60%, seria equivalente a

```
valor * 2 * 1.6
```

Simplificando

```
valor * 3.2
```

### Versão "longa":

Se quiser usar a fórmula em vários ítens com porcentagens diferentes, aí a coisa muda.
Poderia usar uma função para isso:

```
$indice = 2; // Acrescentado com base no comment, que vai ser o índice do dólar.
echo acrescimo( $i['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice'][0]['__value__'] * $indice, 60 );

function acrescimo( $valor, $porcentagem) {
   return $valor * ( 1 + $porcentagem/100 );
}
```

Comment: A versão curta acho que funcionou melhor, pois ainda sou um pouco leigo em PHP. O desafio agora é: o valor citado como '2' na verdade será o quanto o real está valendo a cada 1 dollar.

Comment: @GustavoCave editei a resposta pra acrescentar o `$indice`.

Comment: fiz um script para determinar o valor que será multiplicado por 60% (ou 1.6). Este valor vem através da variável $valor. No caso <?php echo $i['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice'][0]['__value__']; ?> como devo fazer para o '__value__' multiplicar pelo valor determinado pela variável $valor e depois acrescentar 60% ?

Comment: @GustavoCave é o que está na versão longa, só que eu chamei de $indice. na versão curta seria ...'value'] * $valor * 1.6 (ou seja, primeiro multiplica pelo seu $valor, depois poe os 60% em cima do resultado)

Comment: Ótima explicação +1.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim, seguindo a formula para descobrir a porcentagem é: `(numero1/100) * a porcentagem que você quer descobrir`

```
    valor = 10;
    multiplicado = 10*2;
    porcentagem = (multiplicado/100)*60;
    total = multiplicado+porcentagem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vou apenas complementar as respostas, anteriores, pois ambas estão certíssimas:

```
<?php
function acrescenta($valor, $percentual){
    return($valor * ( 1 + ($percentual / 100)));
}
?>
```

Você usa assim (supondo que o valor original seja 50):

```
<?php
$total = $total * 2;
$total = acrescenta(50, 60);
?>
```